# Loop to replace values greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry I am a novice in VBA so any help is gratefully received! 
I'm looking for some VBA code for a loop that will look at a range in Column A and as long as the cell in Column A is not 0, replace the adjacent cell in Column B with the positive value, looping through the range until all cells with data > 0 in Column A have been replaced in Column B. It is also important that blank cells in Column A do not overwrite positive data that may exist in Column B.

This is where I am at the moment:

```
Sub Verify()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Set the range in column N 
    Set rng = Range("N2:n1000")

    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell = 0
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        'write value to adjacent cell
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = *'What do I need here to find the first item of data e.g. N2 in column N?'*

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Are you reading the N column or the A column ?

Comment: You want the positive value of Col A copied to Col B, unless the value in Col A is 0? Do I have that right?

Comment: Plase explain the comment `'What do I need here to find the first item of data e.g. N2 in column N?'`

Comment: Hi there, I'm reading the N column, and wish to copy all values greater than zero to the L column (-2 on the offset).  The N column contains data that will override the data in column L, however, if no override data is present in any of the cells, I want the data in column L to remain as is.  I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to deal with ActiveSheet.Cells as with Range object and offsets :

```
Sub Verify()

    Dim row As Long

    For row = 2 To 1000
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1) <> "" Then ' Not blank
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1) > 0 Then ' Positive
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row,2) = ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the edit to what you started. I made the range dynamic, because I don't like making excel loop longer than it has to. That's my personal preference. The first block of code will copy over anything that isn't 0 or blank, and any negative numbers will be represented by their positive counterpart. That's at least how I understood your question.

Also, this code looks at data in Col N (like you have in your code) and copies the data to Col L. If you want A to B then simply change `rng` to `= ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))` and the `myCell.Offset()` to `(0, 1)`.

```
Sub Verify()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'good form to always define the sheet you're working on
    Set rng = ws.Range("N2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)) 'dynamic range

    For Each myCell In rng
        If myCell.Value <> "" And myCell.Value <> 0 Then 'If the cell isn't 0 or ""
            If myCell.Value < 0 Then  'Then if it's negative, make it positive and copy it over
                myCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = myCell.Value * -1
            Else: myCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = myCell.Value 'otherwise copy the value over
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

If you only want to copy over values that are greater than 0, and ignore 0's, blanks, and negative values, then use this code:

```
Sub Verify()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'good form to always define the sheet you're working on
    Set rng = ws.Range("N2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)) 'dynamic range

    For Each myCell In rng
        If myCell.Value <> "" And myCell.Value > 0 Then 'If the cell is > 0 and not ""
            myCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = myCell.Value 'copy the value over
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Slai, this works perfectly!  I only had to remove the line relating to changing the negative to a positive as the override value in N could be negative and I wanted that copied across.  Thanks once again to everyone who contributed to my thread!

Comment: Did you mean to put this comment on my answer? Could you mark the answer that answered your question? Glad we could help you!

Comment: Sorry Tyeler, it was meant for you , although Slai's answer would also have worked but more generically, whereas yours covered all the areas I requested. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @eagleboy1234 I'm glad to hear that! If you wouldn't mind, could you mark mine as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can "simplify" it to something like this:

```
Sub Verify()
    [b2:b1000] = [if(iferror(-a2:a1000,),abs(a2:a1000),b2:b1000&"")]
End Sub
```

just replace `a2:a1000` with your Column A range and `b2:b1000` with the Column B range.